# Java: non-static method insertValue(int,java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, nodes, non-static

I'm trying to realize a binary tree, more specifically I'm trying to write the method to insert a node in the tree.

A node is composed of an integer key (for the positions of the nodes) and a `String` value (the value inside the node).

The code below is for the node class:

```
public class Node {
    private int key;
    private String value;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;
    public Node(int key, String value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
    public void setLeftChild(Node child) {
        left = child;
    }
    public void setRightChild(Node child) {
        right = child;
    }
    public int getValue() { return key; }
    public Node getLeftChild() { return left; }
    public Node getRightChild() { return right; }
    public int getKey(){ return key; }
}
```

And this is the tree class:

```
public class BinaryTree {
    private static Node root;
    public BinaryTree(){
        root = null;
    }
    public BinaryTree(int key, String string) {
        root = new Node(key,string);
    }
    public void insertValue(int key, String value) {
        insert(key, value, root);
    }
    public void insert(int key, String value, Node currentNode) {
        //base case
        if (currentNode == null) {
            currentNode = new Node(key, value);
        } else {
            if ( key <= currentNode.getKey())
                insert(key, value, currentNode.getLeftChild());
            else {
                if ( key > currentNode.getKey())
                    insert(key, value, currentNode.getRightChild());
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BinaryTree alpha = new BinaryTree(5,"Bella");
        insertValue();
    }
}
```

I get the following error from Java:

> Error:(32, 9) java: non-static method insertValue(int,java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context

I don't understand why. Can someone explain to me why it doesn't work? The idea is correct? The recursion call is correct?

Comment: It's pretty obvious -- which object do you call the `insertValue` method on?

Comment: Yeh sorry, in any case also if I insert insertValue(3,"Alpha") i've the error

Comment: I am sorry but that doesn't answer my question. Even if you think you can call the method with an expression like `insertValue(3, "Alpha")`, which you cannot -- what object do you want to call the method on?

Comment: Oh sorry, i've read the questions too fast. I haven't call the method to an object. Is a stupid Error.

Answer (score 1):

don't declare `Node root` as `static` in this line `private static Node root;`, rather you should do as follows:

```
private Node root; // remove the "static" keyword
```

And you've one more mistake in `main method`

```
// insertValue(); // it is wrong
alpha.insertValue(); // call it like this
```

And you'll be okay...

**Now why this happens**:

To understand why this happens, you've to understand how `static` works in `java`. Anything declared using `static`, may it be `method/variable`, is `shared` between `all objects` of the `class`. And that means, there would be only one instance of the variable for all objects or you may say all objects will share one single variable. Now, this said, no `non-static` `variable/method` can be `used/called` in `method` which is declared is `static` i.e. `static method`. Simply, you can't use a `non-static` `variable/method` in a `static` method. Cause, `static method` belongs to class scope and `this` pointer is not passed into `static method`, so you can not use `non-static` variables/metods.

If you've understood the concept of static, now, let me explain the problems of your code:

**First problem - why `static root` is wrong**:

Cause, if you declare `root` as `static` there'll be `only one root` for all `Binary Tree` you create. But, of course, you'd expect different roots for different binary tree.

**Second problem - why just `insertValue();` calling is wrong**:

You're in `main() method`, notice that `main()` is `static`. But `insertValue()` is `not static`. But, you already know, that you can't call a `non-static` method from a `static` method.

Hope this clears your understanding. let me know if you've any more questions...

Comment: call alpha.insertValue(); not insertValue(); in main method. I've also edited the answer...

Comment: While this is a good answer, please don't user code markup for emphasis, use **bold** or *italic* for emphasis instead. Otherwise, screenreaders will have a hard time reading your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try in main method

```
alpha.insertValue(1,"Something");
```

Comment: Oh, it works ! But i've not understand why. I have to create an istance of a tree ??

Comment: @Kalewi_98 Dou you understand what the `static` keyword does? Do you understand the difference between a *class* and an *object* which is an *instance* of the class? If you put all these basics together, its pretty obvious what happens.

Comment: Thanks @Polygnome, probably i've not understand completely what static does. I'm gonna see it again